# TACACS+ configuration: how to receive priv-lvl value?

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, tacacs+, aaa

I need to configure TACACS+ server to know if the given user is authenticated* and what is his priv-lvl. As a client I'm using tactest (tacacs.net) and TACACS+ Client Java Library (AXL).

I tried with this:

```
user = admin {
    name = “Admin User”
    login = cleartext admin
    service = exec {
      priv-lvl = 10
  }
}
```

and can authenticate as an admin but can't get his priv-lvl.

Here is the output from tactest:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TACACS.net>tactest -s x.x.x.x -k testing123 -u admin -p admin -author -service exec
Trying to open connection to x.x.x.x:49

Sending:
 MajorVersion=12
MinorVersion=0
Type=Authorization
SeqNum=1
IsEncrypted=True
IsSingleConnect=True
SessionID=494431516
DataLength=37
 Authorization Method=Debug
Priv lvl=1
Auth Type=Ascii
Service=None
User=admin
Port=
Rem Addr=
Args: service=exec


Received Header:
 MajorVersion=12
MinorVersion=0
Type=Authorization
SeqNum=2
IsEncrypted=True
IsSingleConnect=False
SessionID=494431516
DataLength=6

Received Body:
 Authorization Status=PassAdd
User=
Port=
Args:

Command Pass status = True, Message=,

------------------

SUMMARY STATISTICS

------------------

Total Commands  .....................  1
Successes  ..........................  1
Failures  ...........................  0
No Results  .........................  0
Time Taken for commands  ............  0,066 secs
Avg Possible Transactions/Second  ...  15
Network Time per command  ...........  0,017 secs
Total Network time  .................  0,017 secs
Sent Transactions/Second  ...........  11,1
```

Is there a way to get that attribute value?

*I'm aware that it isn't only authentication but also kind of authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I just had to change service name to any other:

```
user = admin {
    name = “Admin User”
    login = cleartext admin
    service = myservice {
      priv-lvl = 10
  }
}
```

Then I was able to get AV pair on client side:

```
Received Header:
MajorVersion=12
MinorVersion=0
Type=Authorization
SeqNum=2
IsEncrypted=True
IsSingleConnect=False
SessionID=952769599
DataLength=18

Received Body:
 Authorization Status=PassAdd
User=
Port=
Args: priv-lvl=10
```